# My trigger didnt work he have a problem with the When

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a trigger that automatically adds an end of reign date to the govern table if the datedeath column of the character table is updated. but it doesn't work

```
CREATE TRIGGER maj_date_gouv
AFTER UPDATE OF Datedeath ON Personnage
WHEN (new.Datedeath <> NULL)
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN
UPDATE Govern SET Dateendgov = Datedeath
WHERE IdPersonnage = :new.IdPersonnage
END IF ;
END ;
```

---

```
ORA-04077: WHEN clause cannot be used with table level triggers 
*Cause:    The when clause can only be specified for row level triggers.
*Action:   Remove the when clause or specify for each row.
```

Answer (score 0):

Order matters:

- `for each row` first
- `when`  next
- if you compare something to `null`, then it is either `is null` or `is not null` (not "`<> null`")

So:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger maj_date_gouv
  2    after update of datedeath on personnage
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.datedeath is not null)
  5  begin
  6    if updating then
  7       update govern set
  8         dateendgov = datedeath
  9       where idpersonnage = :new.idpersonnage;
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got another problem now


`3/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`

`3/21      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATEDEATH": invalid identifier`

Comment: It means that DATEDEATH column doesn't exist in that table.